# Как сделать регулярный перезапуск сервиса Ubuntu

Tags: linux

Нужно перезапускать службу `bot.service` каждый день в 00:00 и 12:00. Путь к службе: `/etc/systemd/system/bot.service`. Как это можно сделать?
P.S. Новичок в linux, поэтому буду рад наиболее подробному руководству

Comment: через systemd timers?

Comment: @Sergey можно пример?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055194/how-can-i-configure-a-systemd-service-to-restart-periodically

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, самый простой вариант - использовать демон crond. (man crond). Есть одна тонкость. Если Ваш *bot.service* запускается под Вашим логином, то и редактировать надо Ваш файл *crontab*. А если из под рута, то и редактировать надо системный *crontab*.

Для того, что бы отредактировать *crontab*, необходимо выполнить команду

```
crontab -e
```

Откроется окно текстового редактора VI. В принципе, этот файл можно редактировать любым текстовым редактором. Но команда *crontab -e* выполняет некоторые дополнительные действия, которые уменьшат вероятность поломать систему.

В открывшемся окне нажимаем клавишу "I" (Перейти в режим вставки текста) и дописываем строку вида:

```
0  0,12  *  *  * user-name  Команда перезапуска сервиса
```

После ввода этой  строки нажимаете Enter, Esc, ":", "w" и "q".
Строка добавиться в *crontab* и окно закроется.

Эта строка означает, что:

1. В 0 минут
2. Часов 0 и 12
3. Любого дня месяца
4. Любого месяца
5. В любой день недели

Будет выполнена "Команда перезапуска сервиса" от имени пользователя "user-name".